# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "Invalid URL (POST /v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/chat/completions)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm using OpenAI to learn more about API integration but I keep running across this code when running the Python program. I asked ChatGPT about the `Invalid URL (POST /v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/chat/completions)` error but it didn't seem to give me the right solutions.

*Note: I do have the latest OpenAI package installed (i.e., `0.27.4`).*

Code:

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Tell me a joke."}
]

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    engine="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=messages,
    max_tokens=50,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.7,
)

joke = response.choices[0].text.strip()
print(joke)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Problem

The ChatGPT API (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) has a `model` parameter (required). **The `engine` parameter is not a valid parameter for the `/v1/chat/completions` API endpoint.** See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat).

##### Solution

Change this...

```
engine = "gpt-3.5-turbo"
```

...to this.

```
model = "gpt-3.5-turbo"
```

Also, change this...

```
joke = response.choices[0].text.strip()
```

...to this.

```
joke = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
```

Comment: yeah I kinda figured it out after doing some reading on the open ai page. also apparently the response.choices[0].text.strip() should be ----> response.choices[0]['messages']['content']