# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "Invalid URL (POST /v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/chat/completions)" (migrating GPT-3 to GPT-3.5 API)

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I've been fighting with this for hours. I'm no expert, clearly, but I've gotten this far - api set up, running on front end, when i input the chat prompt, it gets error, and gunicorn returns big long error.

Here is my ai_chat.py latest source (i've been through about 100 variations of this with nearly same failure, and apparently i'm not understanding the api documentation enough to troubleshoot it after working on for so long, feel like i'm in a rabbit hole)

ai_chat.py

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                                                                                   ai_chat.py                                                                                                             
import asyncio
import openai
import functools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

openai.api_key = "AI KEY GOES HERE"
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

def _generate_response_sync(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        prompt=f"User: {prompt}\nAssistant:",
        max_tokens=150,
        n=1,
        stop=["User:"],
        temperature=0.5,
    )

    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

async def generate_response(prompt):
    response = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(_generate_response_sync, prompt))
    return response
```

Below is the error from gunicorn when the user chat is submitted on the frontend website:

```
73.35.113.109:0 - "POST /chat HTTP/1.1" 500
[2023-04-28 20:05:58 +0000] [206218] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 429, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/root/mental/src/main.py", line 37, in chat_post
    response = await generate_response(chat_message.message)
  File "/root/mental/src/ai_chat.py", line 9, in generate_response
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/root/mental/src/ai_chat.py", line 13, in _generate_response_sync
    prompt=f"User: {prompt}\nAssistant:",
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 226, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 620, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "/root/mental/mental/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 683, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Invalid URL (POST /v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/chat/completions)
```

It's running on an apache2 server w/ gunicorn - let me know if you need more info.

building an AI chat bot on web frontend using apache2 and gunicorn to host on my ubuntu server.

api and frontend working, but when submitting chat into the prompt, something is wrong with the engine and chat script i'm fighting with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "Invalid URL (POST /v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/chat/completions)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084296/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-invalid-url-post-v1-engines-gpt-3-5-turbo)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple mistakes in your code. Your code would work with any GPT-3 model, but you want to use the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model (i.e., the GPT-3.5 model). Your current code works with the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api).

**What you need to do is write the code so that it works with the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) if you want to use the GPT-3.5 model.**

Change the following:

- function `Completion` (Completions API) to `ChatCompletion` (Chat Completions API)
- `engine` parameter (Completions API) to `model` parameter (Chat Completions API)
- `prompt` parameter (Completions API) to `messages` parameter (Chat Completions API)
- how you access the message content

*Note: Changing the `engine` parameter to the `model` parameter would solve the `Invalid URL (POST /v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/chat/completions)` error, but if you don't fix all other things as well, you will run into further errors.*

Try this:

```
import asyncio
import openai
import functools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

openai.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

def _generate_response_sync(prompt):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create( # Change this
        model = "gpt-3.5-turbo", # Change this
        messages = [ # Change this
            {"role": "assistant", "content": `{prompt}`}
        ],
        max_tokens = 150,
        n = 1,
        temperature = 0.5,
    )

    return response['choices'][0]['message']['content'] # Change this

async def generate_response(prompt):
    response = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(_generate_response_sync, prompt))
    return response
```

Comment: why do I need to use async?  def gpt_response2(sText):
    messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are an Lousie the AI assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": sText}
    ]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
      engine="gpt-3.5-turbo",
      message=messages,
      temperature=0.7,
      max_tokens=600,
      stop=None
    )
    content=response.choices[0].text.split('.')
    #print(content)
    #print(response["choices"])
    return response.choices[0].text

Comment: @GoldenLion You don't have to. The OP had an async function in the question above, so I left it as is.